# Why is there a big green spot on my taskbar

Tags: taskbar

This green mark has been there for weeks and I dont't know why is it there?[image]

Comment: That's a subtle green tint in a portion of it. I had to move the screen shot to a different monitor to notice it since it's so subtle. Try changing the color and transparency settings, save changes, and then change back and see if that helps. Here's a guide method 1 in particular https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-make-the-taskbar-transparent-in-windows-10 or https://www.alphr.com/how-to-change-windows-10-taskbar-color/

Comment: Is it a hardware problem?